# Show JSON data from URL w/ Parameter

Tags: json, angularjs, rest

I'm having trouble displaying some information from a REST API. Each location_id (2-7) have their own JSON data.

How can I get the data to display for each individual location_id. Below is my code:

Controller:

```
countryApp.controller('ViewLocation', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) { 
        $scope.localeID = $routeParams.localeID; 

        $http.get('http://localhost/slimtest2/location/' + $scope.localeID).success(function(data) { 
            $scope.location = data; 
        });                               
    );
```

View individual item

```
<div ng-controller="ViewLocation"> 
Stuff 
  <div ng-model="location in location.location"> 
      {{ location.location_id  }}

  </div>
</div
```

The JSON Data from http://localhost/slimtest2/location/(location_id). I currently have the location_ids 2-7.

```
{ "location" :[{"location_id":"2","location_reference":"657821349","location_title":"Guam Premier Outlet,? ???? ???","location_category":"Shop,??","location_subcategory":"Shopping Mall,???","location_latitude":"13.489714","location_longitude":"144.781906","location_image":"gpo1.JPG","location_description":"Description test for GPO,GPO | ? ?? ?? ???","location_address":"Tamuning, 96913\r\nGuam | ?? ? , 96913\r\n?","location_village":"Tamuning","location_pricerange":"3","location_price":"100"}]}
```

Comment: you could try `<div ng-model="l in location.location"> {{ l.location_id  }} </div>`

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar, this didn't work.

Comment: see its working here http://plnkr.co/edit/JlGQTNMnNNRckwmVNcLs?p=preview

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar, Yikes, I didn't clearly state what I wanted earlier. It's from a REST API where I get the info from each post and display the individual JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` is used for input types like input fields, textarea and  select only not for div. you are looking for `ng-repeat` to iterate the json object

```
<div ng-repeat="loc in location.location"> 
      {{ loc['location_id'] }}
</div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xvs0qspr55hnBDZ7OVmU?p=preview)

Comment: Now i upated please check

Comment: Otherwise your json is not valid

Comment: just did a test on JSONLint, it didn't find any problems.

Comment: did you put ng-repeat instead of ng-model

Comment: other than you have some issue i think please check I am sure my code is working

Comment: going to check my routes and making sure I'm getting the location_id.

Comment: @JqueryKing Glad to add that if its work for OP Thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar - The OP having some problem rather than this issue.